# How can I update the data automatically without refreshing the page in firebase flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have to display total number of Sales and pending sales in the dashboard. I have designed inside the container.
I need to update that every time new sales adds to Firebase Firestore automatically. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use stream builder or future builder to get data without getting refresh every time.

Here is the docs:

=> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html
=> https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a Streambuilder which listens to Firebase document that has a field called "Sales" and when the field is modified it will automatically be updated in the UI ( Container widget)